# If $X$ is a K3 surface and $X\to C$ is an elliptic fibration, then $C\simeq \Bbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, sheaf-cohomology, k3-surfaces

Sometime ago I heard someone say in a talk that if an algebraic surface $X$ is K3 and has an elliptic fibration $\pi:X\to C$ (where $C$ is a curve), then $C$ must be rational.

The speaker just said this is a simple consequence of the cohomology of $X$.

By definition of K3 surface, $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=0$ and that's all we know about the cohomology. Is that enough to conclude that $H^1(C,\mathcal{O}_C)=0$? Is that enough to conclude $C\simeq \Bbb{P}^1$ (birational equivalence)?

Maybe this is really trivial, but I'm just not very familiar with sheaf cohomology.

Comment: In characteristic zero, use the fact that $H^1(O_X)=0$ if and only if $H^0(\Omega_X)=0$ and the same for $C$. Now if $C$ has a nonzero differential form, you can pull it back to $X$; since we're in characteristic zero the pullback form is still nonzero, a contradiction.

Comment: You can also use that $X$ is simply connected to prove this. If the base of the elliptic fibration $\pi$ were of genus $>0$, then you  can pull-back finite etale coverings of the base (of which there are many) to get non-trivial finite etale covers of $X$.

Comment: Both of these comments seem like answers to me - would either of you care to record them below? @LazzaroCampeotti

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In characteristic zero, use the fact that $H^1(O_X)=0$ if and only if $H^0(\Omega_X)=0$ and the same for $C$. Now if $C$ has a nonzero differential form, you can pull it back to $X$; since we're in characteristic zero the pullback form is still nonzero, a contradiction.

Comment: What do you mean by $\Omega_X$? How do I verify the equivalence $H^1(\mathcal{O}_X)=0\Leftrightarrow H^0(\Omega_X)=0$? If I understood correctly, your argument proves $H^1(C,\mathcal{O}_C)=0$, but does that allow us to conclude $C$ is birational to $\Bbb{P}^1$?

Comment: $\Omega_X$ is the cotangent bundle of $X$. The spaces $H^1(O_X)$ and $H^0(\Omega_X)$ have the same dimension because of "Hodge symmetry". (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_theory) Finally I was assuming that $C$ is nonsingular (if not, I don't think a map $X \rightarrow C$ is really a "fibration"). In this case, $H^1(C,O_C)$ is the genus of $C$, which is 0 if and only if $C$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf P^1$.

Comment: Oh, I see! By the way, I know I didn't specify the base field in the question, but the arguments you used only make sense over $\Bbb{C}$, right? Thank you!

Comment: The argument should make sense over any subfield of $\mathbf C$, because the dimensions of the cohomology groups involved don't change if you change base. I will clarify what I wrote when I have a chance.